# Pandas assign value of one column based on another

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':[10,20,30,40,50,60],
         'B':[1,2,1,4,5,4]
        })
df

    A   B
0   10  1
1   20  2
2   30  1
3   40  4
4   50  5
5   60  4
```

I would like a new column 'C' to have values be equal to those in 'A' where the corresponding values for 'B' are less than 3 else 0.
The desired result is as follows:

```
    A   B  C
0   10  1  10
1   20  2  20
2   30  1  30
3   40  4  0
4   50  5  0
5   60  4  0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['B'] < 3, df['A'], 0)

>>> df
    A  B   C
0  10  1  10
1  20  2  20
2  30  1  30
3  40  4   0
4  50  5   0
5  60  4   0
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you can use `pandas` method [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) direct on the column:

```
In [3]:
df['C'] = df['A'].where(df['B'] < 3,0)
df

Out[3]:
    A  B   C
0  10  1  10
1  20  2  20
2  30  1  30
3  40  4   0
4  50  5   0
5  60  4   0
```

**Timings**

```
In [4]:
%timeit df['A'].where(df['B'] < 3,0)
%timeit np.where(df['B'] < 3, df['A'], 0)

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.4 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 407 µs per loop
```

[`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is faster here but pandas `where` is doing more checking and has more options so it depends on the use case here.

Comment: up to you, the point here is that pandas has a built in method

Comment: Added timings, `np.where` is faster but the pandas method has more options so it depends on the use case